# How do I Join a World in Minecraft: Pocket Edition over Android and iOS?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My sister is using a kindle fire and I am using an IPad. How do I let her into my world and how do I go into hers?

I know this question has already been answered but where do I go to find the answer to this question?

Answer (score -1):

Well if you have wifi on and broadcast to lan and multiplayer world thing on the go on to your world and then and the top of all of your sisters worlds it will say your username and the same thing when your sister does it but this question is a duplicate.
Hope I Helped.